# mootools $clear not defined

Tags: timer, mootools

i have error : $clear is not defined..what's wrong in this code?? I use Mootools 1.4.5:

```
var test = new Class({
    initialize: function(){},


    init: function(){
        var timer;
        $$('#list tr').addEvents({
            'click': function(){
                $clear(timer);
                timer = (function(){
                    console.log('clicked');
                }).delay(200, this);
                },
                'dblclick': function(){
                    $clear(timer);
                    console.log('dblclicked');
                }

            }); 
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$clear` is deprecated since it just replicated the built in `clearTimeout` function.  I would guess it has now been removed.

**edit:** deprecated functions are only included in the "with compatibility" version of Mootools 1.45

Answer (score 2):

The solution would be the following:

replace both instances of:
$clear(timer);

With:
clearTimeout(timer);

There were many functions deprecated after the 1.3 release. Here is a good link to help you upgrade any 1.2 mootools code to 1.3/4

http://www.mooforum.net/help-f26/upgrade-update-guide-t3643.html